# Rendering a View in another View (Not a partial view)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, view, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a ReviewsController and an ActionResults which queries my table in my DB and return them in different views e.g.

In ReviewsController

```
public ActionResult StudentWellnessReviews()
    {
        using (var context = new SizaFakeEntities())
        {
            var userreview = context.Reviews.SqlQuery("select * from dbo.Review where WellnessService='Student Wellness Service'").ToList();

            return View(userreview);
        }
    }
```

And

```
public ActionResult HAICUReviews()
    {
        using (var context = new SizaFakeEntities())
        {
            var userreview = context.Reviews.SqlQuery("select * from dbo.Review where WellnessService='HAICU' ").ToList();

            return View(userreview);
        }
    }
```

StudentWellnessReviews View:

```
<table class="table text-center width:50%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Make Review", "Create", "Reviews", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit Posted Reviews", "ReviewEdit", "Reviews", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" })
                    </td>
                </tr>


                @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Username</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)</div></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Wellness Service</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WellnessService)</div></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Rating</h5>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)</div></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Feedback</h5>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><div align="left"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Feedback)</div></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="2"><hr class="active" /></td></tr>

                }

            </table>
```

HAICUReviews View:

```
<table class="table text-center width:50%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Make Review", "Create", "Reviews", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit Posted Reviews", "ReviewEdit", "Reviews", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" })
                    </td>
                </tr>


                @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Username</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)</div></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Wellness Service</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WellnessService)</div></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Rating</h5>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><div align="left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)</div></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h5>Feedback</h5>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><div align="left"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Feedback)</div></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="2"><hr class="active" /></td></tr>

                }

            </table
```

So both of StudentWellnessReview and HAICUReviews Views display return their respective queries. However what I want to do is display these queries on one View. Your help me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on Kenneth's response:

You could add another action like so:

```
public ActionResult StudentWellnessReviewsAndHAICUReviews()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then in StudentWellnessReviewsAndHAICUReviews.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("ReviewsController", "StudentWellnessReviews")
@Html.Action("ReviewsController", "HAICUReviews")
```

Comment: Btw the correct way to use it is: @{
                                Html.RenderAction("StudentWellnessReviews", "Reviews");
                            }                                                                                      No need to add the word controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RenderAction`:

```
@Html.RenderAction("ReviewsController", "StudentWellnessReviews")
@Html.RenderAction("ReviewsController", "HAICUReviews")
```